# How is it possible to record revSpeak in LiveCode using version 7 on Windows 10?

Tags: livecode

Below, I pasted the code I am trying to use in order to get LiveCode to record while the `revSpeak` command is speaking the words aloud from a text field, but I cannot get any recordings to appear on the desktop or anywhere.
I know that there have been some longstanding audio recording issues with Windows in the past. Does anyone know if those issues are still there or if there is anything wrong with the script I am using? Is there possibly something wrong with the way I am using `specialFolderPath`?

As you can see, I even activated QuickTime in the suggested way but that still doesn't seem to help.

If the `record sound` function is just not possible yet in LiveCode 7, what would be the alternative to being able to record what is being said aloud when revSpeak is speaking whatever text is in a field?

```
on mouseUp
   put the qtVersion into tVersion -- Here, I am activating QT
   ask "Name This Sound Recording"
   put it into tRecordName
   ###set the recordInput to "imic" -- internal microphone
   ###set the recordInput to "dflt" -- default
   ###set the recordInput to "emic" -- external microphone
   set the recordCompression to "raw" -- default
   set the recordRate to 44.1 -- CD quality, default = 22.05
   set the recordChannels to 1 -- mono, 2 = stereo
   set the recordFormat to "wave"
   set the recordSampleSize to 16 -- 8 = default
   put the platform into tPlatform
   if tPlatform is "win32" then
      set the recordFormat to "wave"
      put ".wav" after tRecordName
   else
      set the recordFormat to "aiff"
      put ".aif" after tRecordName
   end if
   record sound file (specialFolderPath("desktop") & slash & tRecordName)
   wait 6 ticks   
   revSpeak word 1 to -1 of field "talkingField"
end mouseUp
```

Any suggestions on how to make this happen or what would be a good alternative to recording the text being spoken will definitely be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some extensive research, and according to Audacity, “Many manufacturers are making it increasingly difficult to record streaming audio by deliberately removing or hiding this functionality due to copyright concerns.”

It seems to be that new sound cards are not allowing one to make a recording from computer playbacks, rather than there being a glitch with LiveCode. So the code was fine, it's just that the new sound cards are preventing it from happening.

Fortunately, I found this most useful link from Audacity that explains the many alternatives for "recording computer playback on Windows." This seems to be a definitive source:

http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/tutorial_recording_computer_playback_on_windows.html

According to Audacity, they suggest two types of software programs to get around this issue. The first program mentioned was SoundLeech and the second program (with the accompanying link pasted below) is a pay program called TotalRecorder, which actually has a Windows 10 version. Both are said to capture the sounds directly from the source, which makes it a higher quality recording than using the old stereo mix:

http://www.highcriteria.com/

After downloading the evaluation editions of both varieties of audio recording software, I had some difficulties with SoundLeech not recording everything but TotalRecorder worked like a charm. Even using the demo standard version of TotalRecorder, the recording sounded perfect.

Hopefully this helps anyone having a similar problem.

Cheers,
Beachcomber Joe